# How to prevent every HTML element from behaving like a link in mobile view

Tags: css, mobile

I have created a mobile view for my site, here.

```
http://105.161.113.68:8080/qualebs/home
```

username = susan
passord = suzzy

if you login from a mobile device with preferably opera mini, you will notice that clicking on any element even the box around the login page reloads the page. I don't know what is responsible for this. please help.

The css for the containing div containing the profile photo, username, and the status is as follows.

```
.feedContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 800px;
    border: solid 1px #f5eabe;
    border-top: none;
    background: #fff;  
}
```

in the css for the mobile page I add the following style

```
.feedContainer{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0px;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

There is no Javascript on the mobile view. My problem Is that every element behaves like a link that if you click it reloads the page. How can I remove this.

example feed container for mobile site looks like this

```
<div class="feedContainer">
                <span class="profileImgContainer">
                    <img class="profileImg" src="img/thumbs/1/1377284547880_1377284934730.jpg" alt="photo"/>
                </span>
                <div class="feedHeader">
                    <span class="time">moments ago</span>
                    <strong>
                        <a href="profile?customerId=1377284547880">susan</a>

                    </strong>
                </div>
                <div class="feed">               


                            <pre><span class="shorten">Hello guys if you are already logged on here, please let me know what you are seeing</span></pre>


            </div>
            <div class="feedFooter">
                <span class="feedFooterWidget">   
                            0
                            <a href="status?statusId=1377338479531&amp;posterId=1377284547880&amp;view=comments">Comments</a>
                </span>
                <span class="feedFooterWidget">
                    <span class="count">
                                0
                    </span>
                            <a class="footerLink" href="like?item=status&amp;itemId=1377338479531&amp;posterId=1377284547880&amp;view=likes">Likes</a>
                </span>
                <span class="feedFooterWidget">
                    <span class="count">
                                0
                    </span>
                            <a class="footerLink" href="share?itemType=status&amp;statusId=1377338479531&amp;posterId=1377284547880">Share</a>
                </span>
                <span class="feedFooterWidget"><a href="message?customerId=1377284547880">Message</a></span>
                <span class="feedFooterWidget"><a href="delete">Delete</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm sorry for future readers of this question the server was running on a local server and I lost the connection.

Comment: If you have no javascript then I would guess that you have an `< href="#">` somewhere that is getting clicked.  Can you post the HTML for the mobile site?

Comment: @SteveGreatrex i have added the sample Html for a full div

Comment: The page is not, for me, behaving as you suggest

Comment: I don't see anything obvious there. Can you post a jsFiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can set `pointer-events:none;` in the mobile css for the elemenet that is triggering the page reload